# Knockout.js - cannot wrap 'with', 'foreach' and other template bindings

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am trying to create a custom binding that wraps an existing binding, namely the "with" or "foreach" bindings that are built into Knockout.

Unfortunately in doing so I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'createChildContext' of undefined` from [knockout-latest.debug.js:3060](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/blob/master/build/output/knockout-latest.debug.js#L3060) (the problem also exhibits on version 2.1.0).

I have reproduced the [exception on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmh_ca/48uJg/1/), with Google Chrome 21.0.1180.57.

The custom binding is simply defined as follows:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myWith = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel) {
        // do things
        return ko.bindingHandlers.with.init(element, valueAccessor,
                                            allBindings, viewModel);
    },

    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel) {
        return ko.bindingHandlers.with.update(element, valueAccessor, 
                                              allBindings, viewModel); 
    }
};
```

One would expect to be able to "wrap" the existing bindings with a simple handler in the form above, much [like it is discussed in this article](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In KO 2.0, binding handlers actually take in a 5th argument that is the binding context.  The binding context holds things like `$data`, `$parent`, `$parents`, `$root`.

So, you just need to forward that parameter on like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myWith = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, context) {
        // do things
        return ko.bindingHandlers.with.init(element, valueAccessor,
                                            allBindings, viewModel, context);
    },

    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, context) {
        return ko.bindingHandlers.with.update(element, valueAccessor, 
                                              allBindings, viewModel, context); 
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/48uJg/2/

or

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myWith = {
    init: function() {
        return ko.bindingHandlers.with.init.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    update: function() {
        return ko.bindingHandlers.with.update.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
```

Comment: That now makes so much sense. :)